# How do I return the object I want by using a key in a forEach loop?

Tags: javascript

Consider this code:

```
const year = 1910;

const items = [
  {
    name: 'gallon of gas',
    year: 1910,
    price: .12
  },
  {
    name: 'gallon of gas',
    year: 1960,
    price: .30
  },
  {
    name: 'gallon of gas',
    year: 2010,
    price: 2.80
  }
]
```

How do I display the price of the object corresponding to the year defined above?

```
items.forEach(d => {
 if (d.year === year) {
   return d.price;
   }
});
```

^ Why doesn't that solution work?

Comment: `forEach()` doesn't return a value. Use `find()` instead.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to only return the prices?  So if that is the case, You should look up the `map(fn)` utility.  Example:    `items.map( item => item.price);`

Comment: `'1910' === 1910` would return false

Comment: sorry, edited the post to make it a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function doesn't return a value, regardless of what you return in the callback function. Use [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead to find the item that matches your criteria:

```js
const year = '1910';

const items = [
  {
    name: 'gallon of gas',
    year: 1910,
    price: .12
  },
  {
    name: 'gallon of gas',
    year: 1960,
    price: .30
  },
  {
    name: 'gallon of gas',
    year: 2010,
    price: 2.80
  }
];

const item = items.find(i => i.year == year);

console.log(item.price);
```

**Note:** you can't use strict comparison (`===`) in the callback to `find()` because you're comparing a year *string* to a year *number*. Probably a good idea to address that.

Answer (score 1):

Because that `return` statement is inside of the handler of the function `forEach`, basically, you're returning the handler execution and not the main function.

What you need to do is either to use a for-loop or the function `find` as follow:

```
let found = items.find(d => d.year === year);
if (found) return found.price;
```

Or a vanilla for-loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) 
   if (items[i].year === year) return items[i].price;
```

Answer (score -2):

This needs ES6 (babel). Hope this helps! Got it from https://zellwk.com/blog/looping-through-js-objects/.

```js
const year = 1910;

const items = [
  {
    name: 'gallon of gas',
    year: 1910,
    price: .12
  },
  {
    name: 'gallon of gas',
    year: 1960,
    price: .30
  },
  {
    name: 'gallon of gas',
    year: 2010,
    price: 2.80
  }
]
const values = Object.values(items)
for (const value of values) {
  //you can't return, but you can use the value or store it in a variable/array
  console.log(value.price);
}
```

Comment: 1) Calling `Object.values()` on an array will just return the array, so you can get rid of that and don't need ES6. 2) Your solution prints out the prices (same as just doing `items.forEach(i => console.log(i.price))`), it doesn't perform a lookup based on the year as was asked in the question.